# NoSuchElementExcpetion when using Java scanner to compare two files

Tags: java, automation, java.util.scanner

I am trying to see the possibilities of automating localization testing of web application(L10N). Firstly, we decided to see if without opening an application, if we can gather HTML plain text(native language)in a file & compare this with the glossary we have.
I am able to get plain text using `jsoup`. Now I am trying to compare these two files with below code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class CompareFiles{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        String curr;

        java.io.File dictionary = new java.io.File("./src/main/resources/Google_JP.txt");
        Scanner dictScanner = new Scanner(dictionary); 

        java.io.File list = new java.io.File("./src/main/resources/Google_JP_HTML.txt");
        Scanner listScanner = new Scanner(list);  
        try
        {
        while(dictScanner.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println("inside dictonary scanner");
            curr=dictScanner.next();
            while(listScanner.hasNextLine()){
                System.out.println("inside list scanner");
                name=listScanner.next();

                if(curr.contains(name)) System.out.println(name);
            }
        }
    }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Now problem with above code is, since I was getting `NoSuchElementException` on `name=listScanner.next();` I tried to handle exception and close the scanner. With this, it is only comparing the first word of html file. How I should make it work, so that it will display all matching words?

Also I am not sure if I am following the right approach to meet the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks to me as if you would need to reinitialize the scanner on every loop iteration as you exhaust it on the first iteration

what happens seems to be:

1. curr is the first line from dictScanner
2. loop over nameScanner

   - curr compared with all names
   - name scanner is now empty
3. curr is set to second line
4. loop over nameScanner which is already exhausted

proposed change:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class CompareFiles{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        String curr;

        java.io.File dictionary = new java.io.File("./src/main/resources/Google_JP.txt");
        Scanner dictScanner = new Scanner(dictionary); 

        java.io.File list = new java.io.File("./src/main/resources/Google_JP_HTML.txt");
        //Scanner listScanner = new Scanner(list);  
        try
        {
        while(dictScanner.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println("inside dictonary scanner");
            curr=dictScanner.next();
            try (Scanner listScanner = new Scanner(list);){
                while(listScanner.hasNextLine()){
                    System.out.println("inside list scanner");
                    name=listScanner.next();

                    if(curr.contains(name)) System.out.println(name);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Yeah, your analysis is the same as I was thinking. But was not good at fixing it in this way. It now matched all the words correctly.

Comment: However, I am still getting an exception `NoSuchElementException` at the end. How should I remove it.?

Comment: there is also a discrepancy in the usage of hasNextLine() and next().
You should use either the combination `hasNext()` and `next()`
or `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()`

this is probably causing the exception and probably also swallowing some of your tokens.

Comment: Yes you are right. I used combination of `hasNext()` & `next()`, since `hasNextLine()` & `nextLine()` gave me only first matching word.